# Google Cloud: How to switch from individual to company account type after a while?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to launch my website on Google Cloud Platform. Initially it is non-commercial project so I've choosed an individual type of account. However later on I would like to make it fully commercial and set up my own company related to this webiste.

How can I change my account type from individual to company easily later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get a gmail business account for your organization then add the new business email as an owner in your project by going to the IAM & Admin option.

You can then set up billing on your business account and then switch it to that.

You would have to get your own domain and business email for that.